# How to filter with indirect association

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm new to Sequelize, I have the following schema (it's an example) :
[image]

How can I use sequelize to get All users that live in a given city,

I looked in Sequelize doc, but I don't figure out how to make indirect association filter.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add an include of the model that has the association on each step.

```
const users = await db.User.findAll({
  include: [{ 
    model: db.Country, 
    as: 'Country', 
    include: [{
      model: db.City,
      as: 'Cities',
      where: {} // here goes your condition
    }]    
  }],
});
```